# How can others use my Waitress/Flask server?

Tags: python, flask, waitress

So I got interested into developing apps using Flask. And saw from the Flask documentation that I can use Waitress (I'm on Windows) to deploy my app (or more so to production). I just made a simple app that returns "Hello World"

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from waitress import serve
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get')
def get():

    return make_response("Hello World with make_repsonse", 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Just the very generic example, I can run it and see it for myself, but how exactly can I have others go to the address and see the message as well? I thought Waitress being a production server would mean that I can deploy this for others to see as long as they have the link. But I can't find any information on this. If I can't, then what is the difference from running the Flask app without Waitress? If I made any mistakes in my assumptions please let me know, as I'm still a beginner at this and might be misunderstanding some of the concepts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The builtin Flask server can only handle one connection at a time.

Waitress can handle many more, depending on its configuration.

Depending on your network and security settings, assuming you develop this app on a pc at work, others can access your app via

```
http://ip_of_your_pc:8080
```

If you want your app to be available world wide, I'd suggest to go to a professional hoster.

Comment: I currently have two laptops with me, sharing the same network. If I were to then run my Flask app on laptop1, and access that address with laptop2 then I should be able to see the page? By security settings I imagine that I might need to have my laptop1's IP address be public right?

Comment: As a first step, I would try to `ping` the other laptop. If that is successfully, try to access the site. When I speak of security settings, these are e.g. firewalls, or your network configuration which could interfere with two pcs connecting. Try it out - and tell us how it worked.

Comment: Okay, got it, I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: Nice! When it works out, I'd be happy about an upvote of my answer! Thanks.

Comment: So, unfortunately, I've been trying to connect, but my other laptop just hangs for a while and then reports back that it couldn't connect. I'll keep trying and see if I can manage it

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow Python through the Windows firewall:

1. Start
2. Firewall & network protection
3. Allow an app through firewall
4. Change settings
5. Tick python.exe
6. OK

Then it will be accessible from other computers on the network, but it's likely with a local IP address that's not visible outside the network. To access it from the rest of the world, configure NAT on your router to allow web requests through to the computer with the server on it then access it using your public IP address (google "what's my IP" to see what it is).